# Badge over custom icon react-native doesn't works properly in react-native

Tags: react-native, badge

I create a custom font based on [this tutorial](https://medium.com/bam-tech/add-custom-icons-to-your-react-native-application-f039c244386c) and everything works ok with the new CustomIcon tag, but, when I use it on a FooterTab, and I want to add a Badge, this last component doesn't work properly, and the Badge position is wrong, just this image:
[image]

The Button in the FooterTab seems like:

```
    <Button badge vertical>
      <Badge>
        <Text>
          8
        </Text>
      </Badge>
      <CustomIcon style={{fontSize: 30}} name='logros_desactivada' />
      <Text>
        Logros
      </Text>
    </Button>
```

The CustomIcon import looks like:

```
import CustomIcon from '../config/CustomIcon';
```

And the CustomIcon file imported above is:

```
import { createIconSetFromIcoMoon } from 'react-native-vector-icons';
import icoMoonConfig from '../../assets/selection.json';
export default createIconSetFromIcoMoon(icoMoonConfig);
```

I tried many ways to locate the Badge in a correct form, but nothings works.

There is another solution?, thanks

Comment: Which `<Button/>` are you using?

Comment: a Button from the native-base library